# show desktop button suddenly stop working

Tags: windows-10

The show desktop button at the bottom right corner suddenly stop working.

It doesn't show the desktop if I click the very bottom right corner, even pressing windows key + D won't show desktop... winkey + M works though.

[image: image description]

I'm running windows 10 x64-bit

Comment: @UlrichGerhardt – please note image embedding is not available at this user reputation. You can edit the post yourself and transform the link into an image.

Comment: Hm, I just tried but got "Failed to upload image; the format is not supported". And I can't access the picture either as picture hosters are blocked in our company.

Comment: @UlrichGerhardt Does not change the fact the author can't do it himself.

Comment: No, but obviously somebody who is able to do it (i.e. not me) could indeed do it. Hint, hint. :-)

Comment: It looks like you have created a second account, which will also interfere with your ability to comment within your thread and to accept an answer. See [How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts) and/or [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts) for guidance on how to merge your accounts.